# Show custom tick value in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have made a plot, and in that plot there is a specific point where I draw vertical line from to the x-axis. This point has the x-value `33.55` for example. However, my tick separation is something like 10 or 20 from 0 to 100.
So basically: Is there a way in which I can add this single custom value to the tick axis, so it shows together with all the other values that where there before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.append` to add to the array of ticks:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(100) * 100
y = np.random.rand(100) * 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.set_xticks(np.append(ax.get_xticks(), 33.55))
```

[image]

Note that if your plot is not big enough, the tick labels may overlap.

If you want the new tick to "clear its orbit", so to speak:

```
special_value = 33.55
black_hole_radius = 10
new_ticks = [value for value in ax.get_xticks() if abs(value - special_value) > black_hole_radius] + [special_value]

ax.set_xticks(new_ticks)
```

[image]

Comment: Would it also be possible to remove ticks ? As you say, if the tick is close to the other ticks, like in your plot, maybe an idea would be to remove 40, and then just let 33.5 stand alone. Can that be done ? Or at least the tick text, and then leave the tick itself as is.

Comment: @DenverDang That *can* be done, but I am not sure if that is really what you want. IMO, ticks are meant for marking regular intervals so that viewers have a sense of scale; something like annotation might be more applicable here. Nevertheless, it is trivial to do something like that, I think. Give me a while.